# elasticsearch using random_score decreases performance

Tags: elasticsearch

When i use random_score in the query, i found that it costs about 150 more milliseconds to get the query result(if not use random_score, it takes about 250 milliseconds to get the result).

**original query**

```
{
"size": 10,
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "fields": [
                                "sound_title",
                                "album_title"
                            ],
                            "query": "0"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "functions": [
            {
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "sound_chapters": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "weight": 1.2
            },
            {
                "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "album_playcount",
                    "modifier": "log",
                    "missing": "100"
                }
            }
        ],
        "score_mode": "sum"
        }
    }
}
```

**query with random_score**

```
{
"size": 10,
"query": {
    "function_score": {
        "query": {
            "bool": {
                "must": [
                    {
                        "query_string": {
                            "fields": [
                                "sound_title",
                                "album_title"
                            ],
                            "query": "0"
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        "functions": [
            {
                "filter": {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {
                                    "sound_chapters": 1
                                }
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "weight": 1.2
            },
            {
                "field_value_factor": {
                    "field": "album_playcount",
                    "modifier": "log",
                    "missing": "100"
                }
            },
            {
                "random_score": {
                    "seed": "123"
                }
            }
        ],
        "score_mode": "sum"
        }
    }
}
```

are there any way to optimize the query to enhance better performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are adding any more function to any `ElasticSearch` query, `ES` would take some processing time to include the score of that function into main score, thereby increasing overall time.
You can read more on Random scoring in elasticsearch [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/random-scoring.html).

Most common way to increase query performance is to use `filters` instead of `query` as filters are cached. But it should be done if you have enough memory in your server.

You can get more ideas from the blog [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/guidance-elasticsearch-tuning-data-aggregation-and-query-performance/).

Comment: thx, but i just don't understand why the performance can decrease that much(from about 250ms to about 400ms). My understanding is that random_score only adds a random score between 0 and 1 to the main score, and in general, generating a random number isn't a time consuming process, so it will only take little more time to include the random_score function score into main score.

Comment: @ThidtcWh it is because random scoring is not purely random. it is `consistently random` scoring which means for same user you will get same random scores, this type of activity will take time to store and fetch data per user. I have added link for random scoring in my answer you should read that one time at least then you will better understand the use of `seed.`

Comment: thank you so much for your patient answering, now i've got better understanding of random_score process